# How to get X Y coordinates in resizable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use the `resize()` method of jQueryUI. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();
    startResizing(event.clientX, event.clientX); // how to get coordinates 
});
```

```html
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

In the function above when the `div` is resized I need to call function named `startResizing()` and pass X and Y coordinates.

My question is how can I get the X and Y coordinates and call the `startResizing()` function each time the div has been resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `resize` event of the resizable method:

```
$(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        resize: function(e, ui) {
            startResizing(ui.position.left, ui.position.right);
        }
    });
});
```

More info available in the jQuery UI documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize